# Preciso colocar um ID no arquivo de impressão usando C# e ItextSharp

Tags: c#, sql-server, itextsharp

**Edit:** se alguem tiver o mesmo problema que eu, eu resolvi jogando o "                    PdfPTable ID = new PdfPTable(1)" pra fora pra ser uma var global e coloquei a parte do "pdfdoc.add(ID)" pra fora do while

Então, para meu trabalho, preciso imprimir um relatório, e quero fazer uma identificação de relatório, no banco de dados SQL já foi criado, porém como vou adicioná-lo ao código para imprimir?

Como tentativa, usei esse código:

```
try
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader registro = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (registro.Read())
    {
        string id = registro["ID"].ToString();
        PdfPTable ID = new PdfPTable(7);
        ID.AddCell(registro["ID"].ToString());
        pdfdoc.Add(ID);
    }
    con.Close()
}
catch
{
  throw;
}
```